# How to get the Unix Timestamp for one month in the future given a date

Tags: php

Suppose I pull a field from the database, a timestamp field.

How do I get the Unix Timestamp, 1 month in the future, from that timestamp field?

My brain is a bit tired, so I need a bit of a re-jogging.

Comment: current_time+60*60*24*30

Comment: That's 30 days into the future, I want a month into the future.

Comment: Thank you guys. I'm being retarded. I'm a bit tired.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
$newDate = strtotime('+1 month',$startDate);
```

Using [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) you can pass it '+1 month' to add a context sensitive month.

Answer (score 7):

I would use the [**`strtotime()`**](http://fr.php.net/strtotime) function, to add `+1 month` to your timestamp :

```
$future = strtotime('+1 month', $current_time);
```

With `strtotime()`, you don't have to think yourself about stuff like "some month avec 30 days, and others have 31", or "february sometimes has 28 days and sometimes 29".

After all, adding one month to a date is a bit harder that adding 30*24*3600 seconds...

You could also work with the [**`DateTime`**][2] class, and methods such as [`DateTime::modify()`][3] or [`DateTime::add()`][4].

Comment: thank you, I wasn't thinking clearly. For some reason, I kept thinking strtotime() only allowed one parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't

```
strtotime('+1 month', $value_from_db);
```

work?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the database.

- MySQL has [TIMESTAMPADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampadd)
- Postgre lets you just add [INTERVAL 1 MONTH](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Working_with_Dates_and_Times_in_PostgreSQL).
- Oracle... is annoying. But you can find out how to do that [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0420__PL-SQL-Data-Types/Adddateintervaltotimestamp.htm).

(Don't know the others, sorry)

Of course there is also `strtotime('+1 month', $current_time);` in PHP. Of course, strtotime is so incredibly easy you might consider it cheating ;-).

Answer (score -2):

How about something like:

```
tm *currTime = localtime(timestamp);

currTime->tm_mon++;

timestamp = mktime(currTime);
```